# OpenFire external authentication password type BCrypt

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp, openfire

Is it possible to use Bcrypt as a password type for openfire external authentication?
The bcrypt with `$2y$` prefix is the encryption of my existing userbase.

I am trying to implement XMPP as an alternative to my current chat system.

```
<jdbcAuthProvider>
  <passwordSQL>SELECT password FROM user_account WHERE username=?</passwordSQL>
  <passwordType>md5</passwordType>
</jdbcAuthProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting the source code and modifying the `auth class`. Coded in `Java`.
I suggest extending `jdbcAuthProvider` or just the `defaultAuthProvider`. It is pretty straight forward.

> This documentation is divided into three sections:
>
> 1. [Source](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html#source), get the Openfire source code.
> 2. [Setup](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html#setup), how to setup your environment for Openfire development.
> 3. [Build tasks](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html#tasks), tasks that can be performed using the build program.

You can then get the bCrypt for Java at [mindrot.org](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).

```
if (BCrypt.checkpw(user_provided_password, hashed_password_from_db))
    System.out.println("It matches");
else
    System.out.println("It does not match");
```